# Rails: Form collection_set, help display text through associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a form to allow a user to create a new review to the trips that a particular user has been on. My reviews table currently have the following columns (rating, trip_id, description). The issue I'm having is displaying the text of city names from trips that the user has been on.

Rails Doc for collection_set accepts the following args: collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}). In terms of the text method, I want to be able to display the actual city name of the trips, however, city names are referenced by the city_id within trips table. I'm not sure how to access this column that exists through their associations.

Trips table(user_id, city_id)
City table(name, description)

```
<%= form_for @review do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :rating %>
  <%= f.number_field :rating %> <br>

  <%= f.label :trip_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select :trip_id, @user.trips, :id, :city_id %>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %> <br>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My first time asking about rails forms, so please let me know how I can update the question to better inform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `city_id` in the `collection_select`, you'll want to use the city name instead. Here's one way to do it:

Firstly, add `city_name` to `Trip`

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  def city_name
    city.name
  end
end
```

Then modify your select:

```
<%= f.collection_select :trip_id, @user.trips.includes(:city), :id, :city_name %>
```

The `includes(:city)` bit will help you to avoid the N+1 query problem, so that every `Trip` won't make a database call for `City`.

Comment: Awesome!! This is exactly what I needed. Could you explain how the method works, specifically how the Trip model has access to the City model. Is it because you need to set up the belongs_to relationship first?

Comment: Exactly that - adding `belongs_to` allows ActiveRecord to know that `city_id` corresponds to a `City`, and it is loaded for you when you access `city`. The documentation on associations explains this well: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html